# Im trying to upload images to my directory in laravel (acces them ith the database)

Tags: database, laravel

So I have looked at multiple articles on the internet and StackOverflow and I'm not able to figure it out.
So when you make a `new user` you won't have an image in you're table column you can edit this in your profile settings. So now I'm trying to add an image to the `directory` and `database` but I'm not getting it too work. I added an `avatar` (representing an image name) into the database as `medium text`.

**MY FORM**

```
<form action="updateImage" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   @csrf
   <div class="modal-body">
   <label for="image" class="custom-image">
     <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i> Select a file
   </label>
   <input id="image" type="file"/>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-footer">
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
   </div>
</form>
```

**MY CONTROLLER**

```
public function updateImage(Request $request)
    {

        $avatar = Auth::user()->id;

  
        if($request->hasfile('image'))
        {
            $file = $request->file('image');
            $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
            $file->move('uploads/face/', $filename);
            $avatar->avatar = $filename;
        }
        

        $avatar->save();
        
        return view('profile');
    }
```

**MY ROUTE**

```
Route::post('/updateImage', 'HomeController@updateImage')->middleware('user');
```

I've already looked at many posts so and still couldn't find a solution. Go easy on me <3.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/filesystem#file-uploads.... $file = $request->file('image')->storeAs('uploads/face/', $filename\);

Comment: Also, you dont want, $avatar = Auth::user()->id; but $avatar = Auth::user();

Comment: You have `user` middleware? Or it would be `auth`? You are using save method `$avatar->save();` but I dont find you call a model, then how can you use save()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You tried to call the save method on `$avatar` an attribute of the Auth::user() (a class), which is just the user's id. Check out the documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent) if you are having trouble understanding how to save eloquent models.

I also don't really understand what `$face` is since you never defined that variable but you're trying to call a method on it.

You probably don't even need to save the user object again since you're just updating an image. Instead, you could just save the file in a directory corresponding to the user's unique identifier. Something like:

```
 if($request->hasfile('image'))
    {
        $file = $request->file('image');
        $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $file->move('uploads/face/'.Auth::id().'/', $filename . $extension);
    }
```

would work fine for the first upload. For additional uploads, you'll have to check if the user already has an avatar then remove the file and replace it with the new file.

If you wanted to instead save the file name as an attribute of your user in the database, you'd have to first update your migrations to add an attribute for that filename. Then something like:

```
 $filename; 

 if($request->hasfile('image'))
    {
        $file = $request->file('image');
        $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $file->move('uploads/face/', $filename . $extension);
    }
    $user = Auth::user();
    $user->avatar = $filename;
    $user->save();
```

would work fine.

Hope this helps. I would recommend watching a video tutorial for Laravel because those helped me a bunch.

Comment: Thank you for helping me get on the right path I got it figured out in the end